# DRYer prompt and assignment in Zsh

Tags: zsh

I would like to do something that accomplishes the same thing that this does:

```
[[ -z "$TICKET_NUMBER" ]] && read "TICKET_NUMBER?Ticket Number? "
```

but that is more condensed, along these lines (but which actually works):

```
: ${TICKET_NUMBER:=$(read "TICKET_NUMBER?Ticket: ")}
```

I've looked in the [Zsh docs for read](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-read) to see if there's a way to pass the input to `read` to STDOUT, but nothing looks like it can do that.

The ideal would be some command that passes the value directly with as little ceremony and repetition as possible.  Imagine a `get_value` command:

```
: ${TICKET_NUMBER:=$(get_value "Ticket: ")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument of the previous command is stored in the `_` parameter, so you can capture the argument to the `-v` operator.

```
test -v TICKET_NUMBER || read "$_?Ticket? "
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little ugly, but it works:

```
: ${TICKET_NUMBER:=$(read "?Ticket: "; echo "$REPLY")}
```

It's certainly not the ideal I'm going for, but it might be one step closer.